# SharePoint 2013 Chrome Control Options

Tags: controls, sharepoint-2013

I cannot find a list of all possible options for SharePoint 2013 Client Chrome Control. I found examples like this:

```
var options = {
    'appIconUrl': hostlogourl,
    'appTitle': document.title,
    'appHelpPageUrl': 'Help.html?' + document.URL.split('?')[1],
    'settingsLinks': [
        {
            'linkUrl': 'Account.html?' + document.URL.split('?')[1],
            'displayName': 'Account settings'
        },
        {
            'linkUrl': 'Contact.html?' + document.URL.split('?')[1],
            'displayName': 'Contact us'
        }
    ]
};
```

Could anybody provide the whole list of options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking through SP.UI.Controls.Debug.js, here are the options:

- siteTitle
- siteUrl
- clientTag
- appWebUrl
- onCssLoaded
- assetId
- appStartPage
- rightToLeft
- appTitle
- appIconUrl
- appTitleIconUrl
- appHelpPageUrl
- appHelpPageOnClick
- settingsLinks
- language
- bottomHeaderVisible
- topHeaderVisible

Some of these are provided and managed by the app framework. The type can be inferred by the option name.  Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a page on MSDN that explains all of the options yet.